# what is the difference if I take max(abs(m) or max(m)?

Tags: algorithm, encoding, communication, decoding, pcm

What is the difference if I take `max(abs(m))` or `max(m)` in Matlab, where `m` is the speech signal used in pulse coding modulation to find `delta`?

```
delta=2.0001*max(abs(m))/L and 
delta=2.0001*max(m)/L
```

Comment: what is `delta` and `L` in your case? if you have unsigned signal then there is no difference but for signed signal the abs(max) find the biggest peak no matter the sign (it can be below zero) btw I would expect that `delta=(max(m)-min(m))`unless your signal is non biassed from zero and to obtain proper bit length for diferential encoding multiplied by precision constant (I suspect that is the `2.0001/L` for but just guessing...If you want to obtain the bit count for plain PCM then your formulas are OK)

Comment: L8=2.^n8;                                                   %The quantization levels = 2^9
delta8=2.00001.*max(abs(m))/L8;                                                                  %Defining delta: quantization error for L=512

Comment: for the case of 9 bits I used delta to decod the speech correctly by this                       >>>

Comment: mq8= delta8.*floor(m/delta8) + delta8/2;      %The recoverd speech with number of bits=9

Comment: can you explain more to me why delta=2.0001*max(m)/L. will not work I didn't get your point exactly

Comment: m is my voice recorded in mat lab

Comment: but has positive and negative values or just positive or just negative?

Comment: I plot my voice it has both positive and negative values

Comment: then you should probably use the `max(abs(m))`

Comment: yes .. and the recovered voice is perfect but

Comment: but why when i use max(m) it did not work

Comment: what is the difference if I take max(abs(m)) or max(m) ?

Comment: because max(m) ignores the peaks below zero .... it just finds maximal positive value not max |value| and when you encoding you need to hold all the used numbers not just positive so when your signal has bigger negative values then positive it get cut off (distorted/overflowed glitchy sound)

Comment: so my voice will not be symmetric about the x-axis .... if it is  the case max(m) will work fine right ?

Comment: may or may not for that I would need the diagram of encoding scheme you are using. It also depends on how big chunk of data you are encoding at once if the buffer is too small to fit one whole period of smallest sampled carrior frequency then the problem will be still there ...

Answer (score 0):

**Summary answer from mine comments (to make it more comprehensible I hope)**

You got signed signal (possibly with small zero bias)

- so you should use the `max(abs(m))`
- to avoid overflow errors due to invalid signal magnitude computation
- this is the case even if the signal is symmetrical
- let see:
- [image: symmetrical signal example]
- the green area is actually processed audio buffer
- first example shows too small buffer
- in this case you can miss the peaks even with `max(abs(m))`
- the result is shifting of peak up and down
- resulting in falsely compute too low bit count/step quantization constants
- that leads to overflows and signal distortions (glitches in sound and weird echo like or underwater sounds)
- The second example is big enough buffer size (have at least one whole period of carrior signal)
- in this case for symmetrical signals the `max(m)` should work but you should add some small gap just to be sure
- of coarse if any zero bias is present then you are screwed (unless you know its value)
- the Red,Blue lines represents obtained dynamic range (your delta without scaling)
- so as you can see the if you use `max(abs(m))` then the buffer size can be half of what it needs to be for `max(m)` case (of coarse only for symmetrical signals)
- magenta is red+blue